# Send additional data back to calling activity when a library calls setResult

Tags: android, zxing

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) based on Zxing to scan several barcodes and I need to pass which I'm currently scanning to the ScannerActivity and back to the calling activity.

Currently I call the ScannerActivity like this:

```
new IntentIntegrator(this)
                .setOrientationLocked(false)
                .addExtra(SCAN_TYPE_EXTRA, scanType.getValue())
                .setCaptureActivity(ScannerActivity.class).initiateScan();
```

Then I'm able to get the `SCAN_TYPE_EXTRA` value like this:

```
this.getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.SCAN_TYPE_EXTRA, 1)
```

I need to send this value back to the calling activity (`MainActivity`), however the `zxing-android-embedded` library calls the `setResult` and `finish` methods on its own.

How can I add my data to the library data when the ScannerActivity is being finished?